# Слогообразующий звук

Tags: словообразование

Может ли в русском языке функцию слогообразующего звука в слове взять на себя глухой согласный?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Это противоречило бы закону восходящей звучности. 
Только сонорный. Да и то истинность такого слога не всеми признаётся.